# VueJS input placeholder text not displaying

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to add a dynamic placeholder to my input field in my `vue`-app, so I did the following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="text" :placeholder="placeholder" />
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: '',
      placeholder: 'Some placeholder text'
    }
  }
}
```

so far so good, but for some reason I don't know, the placeholder text is not visible/displayed even though, when I inspect the input, the placeholder text is visible in the `DOM` ??

What am I missing here?

Comment: try using the place holder assignment like this :placeholder="[[ placeholder ]]"

Comment: @user3396478 your suggestion and adding a color to the `css` (since the background color of the input was white) made it work! Even though `:placeholder="placeholder"` also works

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `script` tag

try

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="text" :placeholder="placeholder" />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: '',
      placeholder: 'Some placeholder text'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, that was not it, I just forgot to copy/paste the script tag into the question :p

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself! Since the `background-color` of the input was white, I had to add some color to the `css`, so it finally has come to work!

Answer (score 0):

I also found out my input component BG color has been set as "bg-grey-800"(tailwind CSS): so I changed it. it works!
Thanks

Comment: This answer seems more like a comment.